# Creating a loop for modifying a variable while creating time buckets (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, loops, time

I am calculating the time difference between first call and when the id for the customer was created.

My Query looks like this :

```
case when (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM call_time - creation_date) / 60)::Integer between 0 and 60 then '0 to 1'
     when (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM call_time - creation_date)) / 60)::Integer between 60 and 120 then '1 to 2'
...
```

Now my aim is to create buckets until I hit '47 to 48', it is a very tedious procedure, and I was wondering whether there is a loop option for Postgresql users.

My data looks the following, where I wish to create a bucket column (blue), expressing that time difference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arithmetic.  How about just starting with numbers of hours?

```
FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM call_time - creation_date) / (60 * 60)) as hours
```

If you want this in a string:

```
(FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM call_time - creation_date) / (60 * 60)) || ' to ' ||  FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM call_time - creation_date) / (60 * 60)) + 1)
```

If you want to limit this to a maximum bound, then use a `CASE` expression:

```
(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM call_time - creation_date) / (60 * 60) < 48
      THEN (FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM call_time - creation_date) / (60 * 60)) || ' to ' ||
            FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM call_time - creation_date) / (60 * 60)) + 1
           )
      ELSE 'WAY TOO LONG'
 END) as bucket
```